# Web.config appsettings

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I use the key value that is inside my web.config directly from the asp.net webpage i.e using the <%$ %>

Answer (score 4):

See [ASP.Net Expressions Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx)

Example from that page

Web.config...

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="copyright" value="(c)Copyright 2004 Northwind Traders"/>
</appSettings>
```

Then you can use...

```
<%$ AppSettings: copyright %>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key_name"] %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
<%$Appsettings:KeyName %>
```

Should do what you need.

This uses the `AppSettingsExpressionBuilder` described here https://web.archive.org/web/20110107080439/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/printPage.aspx?path=/articles/022509-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mySetting"] %>
```